# C++: find() with custom == operator

Tags: c++, c++11, find, operator-overloading

I have a case where apparently no operator== is defined for external class and I need to use a find() function. I know I could do this step by step, but I wonder - is there a way to define custom == operator for this find function, similar how we define Hash function for unordered_set? The case:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <MathGeoLib/Math/float3.h>

bool operator==(const math::float3 &lhs, const math::float3 &rhs){
   return lhs.x == rhs.x;
}

int main(){
   std::vector<math::float3> V;
   ...
   std::find(V.begin(),V.end(),math::float3(0,0,0));
}
```

returns

```
binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type math::float3' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Sometimes I would like to find not exact same vector, but vector close enough - here I would just override `operator==` with more suitable. Is there any smart way to do that?

Comment: Hm, I found 'search' function in `algorithm` module, i think it may be more suitable.

Comment: Not sure I understand your problem.. defining a custom comparator seems the right way.

Comment: I doubt the exact program above returns that exact error.  Can you post an exact program (even replacing `...` with `//...` so it, as posted, actually compiles), compile it, and post the exact and complete error message you get?  Not "this is the same with irrelevant details removed so I can post the error message I get in my real program", and not your real program, but a simple one **and the error message from the simple one**.  And **complete** errors, and **all** of them, not a summary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `std::find_if`, here is an example where `value_type` is `double`.
The function `cmp` compares for exact equality, and `cmp_epsilon` compares for equality within some epsilon.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

bool cmp(double a, double b)
{
    return a == b;
}

bool cmp_epsilon(double e, double a, double b)
{
    return a + e >= b and a - e <= b;
}

using namespace std::placeholders;

int main() {
    std::vector<double> A = {3./2, 2, 1};

    auto i1 = std::find_if(A.begin(),A.end(),std::bind(cmp, 61./40., _1));
    std::cout << std::distance(A.begin(), i1) << std::endl;

    auto i2 = std::find_if(A.begin(),A.end(),std::bind(cmp_epsilon, 0.1, 61./40., _1));
    std::cout << std::distance(A.begin(), i2) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For clarity, I would implement a custom find function that accepts a way to compare the elements:

```
template<class InputIt, class Compare, class T>
InputIt custom_find(InputIt first, InputIt last, Compare comp, const T& value)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        if (comp(*first, value)) {
            return first;
        }
    }
    return last;
}
```

You can then give the body of your `==` operator as a lambda to `custom_find`:

```
int main(){
    std::vector<math::float3> V;
    ...
    custom_find(V.begin(), V.end(), 
             [] (const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) { return your_way_to_compare(lhs,rhs); }, 
             math::float3(0,0,0));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `operator==` for anything else than full equality is playing with fire: nobody will expect it, not even you in a couple days/weeks.

---

Nonetheless, your issue here is likely due to name look-up.

**In C++, you should declare free functions in the namespace of *one* of their arguments**. In this case, you should define your `operator==` in the `math` namespace.

In short, this is because the compiler starts looking for the right overload in the namespace of the arguments, and stops gathering more overloads to inspect as soon as it has found namespaces that contained some functions... thus it never checks the global namespace.